# "No root node! Parsing failed?" when editing attribute table on QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing

I have added a delimited text layer to a map. It includes city names, latitude and longitude. Special characters appear as � and I want to edit them to have the correct names. I did not manage to do that directly on my imported layer, so I went to Layer > Save layer as. This created a new layer that I can edit via Open attribute layer > Toggle editing mode, but when I save the changes I get the following message:

> An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string:
>
> No root node! Parsing failed?

The names are successfully changed but the symbols appear yellow with a red cross. What is the issue and how can I fix it? Are there easier ways to edit the attribute table?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE ! Did you checked the `Data source encoding` in the layer properties ? Documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#settings

Comment: The layer properties window lacks the data source encoding field. If I close the settings part and open it again, the data source encoding field appears but it is empty.

Comment: You should redo the "add a delimited text layer" step taking care to set the proper encoding there (the setting should be next to the layer name box at the top), it will be easier to get it right there rather than editing or trying to fix it later...

Comment: To image the @J.R 's comment : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/_images/delimited_text_dialog.png . Try to get your delimited text base encoding before importing it in QGIS.